# Google Script to add a new row with formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where i want to add a new row at the top of a table and copy formulas from a static row.

For example, the table data starts at row 5. So the script will add a new row at this point and copy formulas from row 4 (which is a 'master row').

Thank you

Comment: What type of formulas? Maybe an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you're looking for...it's a good first script with opportunities to build on it to do more complex things:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'InsertRow', functionName: 'insertRow'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Functions', menuItems);
}  //end function


function insertRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(5);

  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(5, 1));
} //end function
```